# Site-To-Site VPN for internal traffic only

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn

I'd like to connect my home network with my office network.  At my office (host) I have a Cisco ASA 5510 ready to go.  At my home network I'd like only work traffic to flow through the tunnel (meaning my home network relies on its own gateway and internet).  What device would be best for my home network to connect it?  I use to use Cisco 877 between remote offices but I remembered running into issues where domain workstations on the remote network could never hostnames of the servers on my host network (like my file or mail server).

I also have an IP Phone on the home network I'd like to be able to hit our phone systems IP address, but if it is on a different subnet would it?

Trying to wrap my head around this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that supports IPSec should theoretically be able to connect to the ASA. On the ASA side, just make sure that split tunneling is enabled for this VPN connection. That will allow only certain subnets to be routed over the Site-to-site tunnel.

Keep in mind, though, that doing this significantly increases your work network's exposure and adds additional attack vectors. I'm not sure if you have family members or friends that use your home network, but if you do, make sure that they're on a subnet that doesn't get access to the Site-to-Site tunnel.

Comment: Thanks for this info... yes... there will be kids and other devices on my home network.  So I would have two subnets on my home network: one for site-to-site traffic, and one solely for internet traffic?  This is where the split tunnel comes in?  I have some readin to do :)  Thanks.